# Confusion about using a where clause, date interval, and 'and' and or 'or', should be quick

Tags: mysql, date, where-clause

```
SELECT *
FROM romantic_dates
WHERE
asker = 'lover' AND date_start BETWEEN NOW() + INTERVAL 90 DAY AND NOW() - INTERVAL 31 DAY
OR
giver = 'lover' AND date_start BETWEEN NOW() + INTERVAL 90 DAY AND NOW() - INTERVAL 31 DAY
ORDER BY date_start DESC;
```

This is a where clause I am building. I am confused on just how to use the 'or' and between now() and interval. Anyone available to help? This question is slightly different then the others I searched for in that there are docs on one or the other on and off stackoverflow, but not dealing with both.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Does this query produce an error? The wrong results?

Comment: Use `(asker ='lover'...31 DAY) OR (giver='lover' ...31 DAY) order by...` for clarity. Can you elaborate on what the confusion is?

Comment: [Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

Comment: no results is the problem, whereas there are entries in the db for the whole range, and outside of that range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operands for `between` are ordered, so the first needs to be less than the second.  That is not the case with your expression.  So:

```
SELECT rd.*
FROM romantic_dates rd
WHERE (asker = 'lover' AND date_start BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 31 DAY AND NOW() + INTERVAL 90 DAY) OR
      (giver = 'lover' AND date_start BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 31 DAY AND NOW() + INTERVAL 90 DAY)
ORDER BY date_start DESC;
```

I would be inclined to factor out the date expression and use:

```
SELECT rd.*
FROM romantic_dates rd
WHERE date_start BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 31 DAY AND NOW() + INTERVAL 90 DAY AND
      'lover' in (asker, giver)
ORDER BY date_start DESC;
```